# Is there any way to register my own csp in iOS

Tags: ios, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I would like to create my own CSP (cryptographic service provider) with non standart cryptographic algorithms (like GOST etc)
Is there any way for me to register it in ios, so the other applications may use my csp through standart ios security interface?
p.s without jailbreak =)

p.p.s. sorry for my poor english =)

Answer (score 1):

No.  Apps on iOS are strongly separated from each other.  One app cannot provide services to another app, except to open URLs or document files.